# A .net sdk/ api for doucment comparison (docx/pdf/pptx) with near ms-word functionalities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, comparison, aspose, groupdocs

I'm trying to make a document comparison viewer for web browser that feels as same as Microsoft word's 'Track Changes' and 'Compare' (options available in Review Tab).
I am already using Aspose.Words to convert every file type to docx and compare two files which gives me a redline copy merged into one single document. What i want to get is the resulting document(s) in a **side by side comparison** on UI. Also i want to give the ability to do the basic:

1. Get a summary of changes made and able to navigate as to where to changes are made in the document.(Scroll to the position of change in the document,  just like Review Pane in MS word)
2. Accept and Reject those changes and download the revised document.
3. Able to compare text as well as non text related changes.

I've looked for many 3rd party tools but always end up in a limitation surrounding them, to list a few

1. GroupDocs.Comparison - Gives navigation and auto scroll but in a
   merged document not in side by side view. Also, does not gives a document but a set of images.
2. Draftable - Compares only text and style, no image/tagged file
   objection insertion or deletion. No option to accept or reject
   changes
3. ipdf-net - No option to accept or reject changes.
4. PrizmDocs Document Compare API -  No navigation to where the change is made in the document. Also no side by side comparison.
5. Litera Compare: No side by side comparison.

Where i could such 3rd party SDK that would help me achieve my objective or is there any was i could overcome the limitations i am getting from the tolls I've looked at ? The main concern is to have a navigation/mapping of change made to its position in the document and ability accept or reject those changes.

Comment: MS provides online editor (Web Application Open Platform Interface (WOPI) ), but it is lacking behind in options it gives compared to desktop application. In terms of tracking revisions or comparing , the only thing you can do there is to enable or disable  track changes for online editing session.

Answer (score 1):

GroupDocs.Comparison provides following features:

- Accept or reject detected changes
- Get comparison summary page
- Get list of changes
- Get changes coordinates
- Customize style changes
- Adjust comparison sensitivity
- Text and image comparison

Learn more about all the supported features in [developer guide](https://docs.groupdocs.com/comparison/net/comparison/). We are also investigating the possibility to implement side by side comparison of the documents. You'll be notified as there's any progress update.